# Update user which are in (SELECT .... ) list

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to update all records of users who their id are not selected in in the list. Any suggestion that how I can do the below query correctly?

```
UPDATE credit SET val = 0 
WHERE u_id not in (SELECT u_id FROM credit WHERE type = 10 and month(create_m)=5)
```

Comment: which dbms are you using? did u tried the above query?

Comment: If you are using sql server and u_id is not null, i think you already have the answer. For mysql, you may want to avoid "not in" or "in".

Comment: to avoid " not in ", what instead can use

Comment: What is your problem with your current query? ;).

Comment: error, wont accept select statement in update

Answer (score 0):

Why you need a select query to do this. Try this.

```
UPDATE credit SET val = 0 
WHERE type <> 10 
and month(create_m)<>5
```

**Update** `Not In` clause will fail when the `sub-query` returns any `NULL` values so use `Not Exists`

```
UPDATE C SET val = 0 
FROM  credit C
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM credit C1
                  WHERE C.u_id =C1.u_id
                  AND   C1.type = 10 
                  AND   month(C1.create_m)=5)
```

Comment: because the user id may have other records which types are not equal 10 and the month also not 5, i dont want those record effected

Comment: @Pentagon - This will also update the records where `types` are not equal `10` and the `month` also not `5`

Comment: in the question i asked, first need to get ids , then update other ids ,(the reason is: if an id even has a single record match with the query , shouldn't update other records of this id, which even doesn't match.

Comment: @Pentagon - Updated try now

Comment: what do u mean by C when we didnt assign it to any table yet ?
i mean in first line?

Comment: @Pentagon - We assigned `C` to `Credits` table in **second line** so it will update `Credits` table. For more info check  http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,366185,366185

Comment: @Pentagon - There was a small mistake. Try now

Answer (score 0):

You use condition not equal: `<>`:

```
UPDATE credit SET val = 0 
WHERE type <> 10 OR month(create_m) <> 5
```

Comment: u_id may has a single record mach and other records which not match and i dont want other records  of the same user update since a single record match .